# Pycharm moved project file | broken path link

Tags: pycharm

I've just started working with PyCharm and moved a project folder from downloads to desktop. After restarting PyCharm it of course didn't recognize the path file but also didn't offer an option to relink.

I now opened the project via folder and all files are in Pycharm yet although streamlit and panda is recognised as packages it didn't run the commands in the terminal.

I get error messages like this.

```
zsh: command not found: streamlit
```

When it should actually open the streamlit browser.

What can I do?

I checked the interpreter and the packages, but all looked okay in my newbie eyes